# My app doesn't close Excel thread after execution

Tags: c#, excel

I need help with the code I have in my app. It suppose to clean and close everything after is executed but clearly it doesn't. It leaves the Excel file as blocked for editing even after closing the VS and it "remembers" the row count from the previous file. What am I missing?

Code:

```
public static void GetGeographicData()
    {


        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Dominik\source\repos\AStar_Dijkstra_DG\AStar_Dijkstra_DG\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\coords2.xlsx");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        Coordinates = CreateCoordinatesArray(rowCount, colCount);

        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {


                Coordinates[i - 1, j - 1] = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2;
            }
        }

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

        xlWorkbook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp.Workbooks);

        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using Excel Interop use a library that can read Excel files directly, like ExcelDataReader, ClosedXML or EPPlus. Any of these choices will be a lot faster, not to mention simpler, than installing Excel on the client machine, starting it up and making a cross-process call to read each cell value

Comment: As for what's wrong, at least one problem is that the Excel objects aren't disposed before calling `GC.Collect()`. Any error will leave the objects and Excel active. There may be other problems. Excel interop is so heavy it's rarely used to read Excel files

Comment: I was wondering why it take so much time to read xlsx... I couldn't find an example how to import the data from file to 2d array using ExcelDataReader. Could You point me to somewhere when I can learn this?